# how to implement IApplicationBuilder?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-1.1

I went through the documentation given in : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

I understood that IApplicationBuilder gives us the ability to plumb in different features in the pipeline.

Is it possible to see the implementation of IApplicationBuilder in the framework ?

If yes, can I write my own version of IApplicationBuilder and override the pipeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can see the implementation of IAppbuilder [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/9f6e09af6bf203744feb5347121fe25f6eec06d8/src/Microsoft.Owin/Builder/AppBuilder.cs)

Not sure why you would like to implement IAppbuilder.You do not have to do that normally unless you would like to create a new server implementation similar on [OWIN specification](http://owin.org/) .

[OWIN is a specification](http://owin.org/spec/spec/owin-1.0.0.html) and for OWIN implementation,you can look at any of these projects

- [katana](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/)
- [NoWin](https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin)
- [Suave](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave)

if you would like to add any Server Feature implementation,you can do that using [Server Feaure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/request-features) .

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. OP is asking about .net core, this is for OWIN. wrong version.